# Какая разница между словами «Сенсор», «Датчик», «Сканер»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

Какая разница между словами «*Сенсор*», «*Датчик*», «*Сканер*»?
Также интересует какое слово использовать в контексте функции Touch ID на iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

**Сенсор** и **датчик** - в большинстве случаев одно и то же. Ранее в значении считывания физических величин и напр. определения состояния использовался преимущественно (если не исключительно) русский термин. Термин "сенсор" поначалу употреблялся только по отношению к устройствам, реагирующим на прикосновение человека ("сенсорные устройства": кнопки и клавиатура - touch pad и пр.) - в таком смысле и сейчас верен именно этот вариант. Однако сейчас термин "сенсор" расширенно стал применяться и в значении "датчик" (видимо, связано с переводами).

"**Сканер**" первоначально закрепилось за компьютерным датчиком считывания изображений. Смысл названия - в осуществлении действия "развертки" (scanning), связанного с последовательным во времени считыванием датчиком условных элементов (в цифровой технике эти элементы дискретны), например, *элементов изображения* (в дискретном представлении, пикселов/пикселей - pic[ture] cells). Наиболее широко термин *развёртка* применяется в телевидении и измерительной осциллографии. Термины "сканирование" (был известен из радиолокации) и "сканер" чаще применяются по отношению к принципиально новым устройствам (что обычно оправданно), но по причине того, что в английском "сканирование" и "развёртка" не различаются (scanning в обоих случаях), в совр. переводах из области телевидения встречаются и ошибки от незнания русской телевизионной терминологии (lines - "линии" вместо "строк", "сканирование" вместо "развёртка" и др.).